# calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x + \ln2x}{\ln x^2}$

Tags: limits

I've been asked to calculate:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x+ \ln2x}{\ln x^2}$$

This is my attempt:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x + \ln2x}{\ln x^2} = 
\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln x + \ln2x}{\ln x + \ln x} =
$$
$$\ln x = t$$
$$x = e^t$$
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t + \ln2e^t}{t + t} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t + t \cdot\ln2e}{t + t}$$
$$\frac{1 + \ln2e}{2}$$
The answer should be 1 and $\frac{1 + \ln2e}{2}$ does not compute to $1$.

**Why is my answer wrong and how can I solve it?**

Comment: While $\ln e^t = t\ln e = t$, it is **not** true that $\ln (2e^t) = t\ln (2e)$. You may want to use $\ln 2e^t = \ln 2 + \ln e^t$ instead.

Comment: $\ln x+\ln 2x=\ln2+\ln x^2$

Answer (score 4):

The mistake's already been pointed out, but why not directly?:

$$\frac{\log x+\log 2x}{\log x^2}=\frac{\log x+\log 2+\log x}{2\log x}=1+\frac{\log 2}{2\log x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}1+0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

$\ln(2x)=\ln(2)+\ln(x)$ and $\ln(x^2)=2\ln(x)$, then is equivalent to $1/2+1/2+\ln(2)/(2\ln(x))$

Putting $x\to \infty, 1/2+1/2+\ln(2)/(2\ln(x))\to 1/2+1/2=1$

Answer (score 0):

your term is for $x>0$ equivalent to $$\frac{2\ln(x)+\ln(2)}{2\ln(x)}=1+\frac{\ln(2)}{2\ln(x)}$$ and this tends to one for $x$ tends to $\infty$